# button with image dont working after refresh

Tags: jquery, html, css, button

Please, can you help me with this problem?

[Here's the link](http://www.abitec.sk/lovell/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=139)

The button is under "Velkostna tabulka" image and I can't click anywhere i.e. the buttons don't work until refreshing the page, sometimes they do.

Removing the image from the button makes it work fine

How can I make the button work with the image?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The error in the console says 'jquery is not defined'

Please refer to this:

[JQuery - $ is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your console? There are some errors and warnings, one regarding an image:

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html:       

     "http://www.abitec.sk/lovell/". jquery-1.7.1.min.js:4f.cssHooks.(anonymous function).get 
     jquery-1.7.1.min.js:4f.extend.css jquery-1.7.1.min.js:4f.fn.(anonymous function)   
     jquery-1.7.1.min.js:4c.fn.(anonymous function) jquery-ui-     
     1.8.16.custom.min.js:15CloudZoom.init cloud-zoom.1.0.2.js:173CloudZoom.init2 cloud-zoom.1.0.2.js:158(anonymous function) 
     cloud-zoom.1.0.2.js:318f.event.dispatch jquery-1.7.1.min.js:3h.handle.i
```

You also have a Uncaught ReferenceError.

Walk through the errors in your console and try to fix those, I hope that will solve your problems.

If not, please post back so we can have a closer look.

Comment: i a post back, please, can you help me? Thanks a lot !